# Count the number of messages in a given time period

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

For a Discord server, I have a bot that whenever the frequency of messages from members is too great, the bot enables slowmode. The problem is that I do not know how to tackle the problem (i.e. how do you detect the number of messages in any time span?). I just need to divide `numberOfMessages` by `timePeriod` (`timePeriod` will reset itself every 10 seconds so that we take the average messages per 10 seconds.)

---

How do I get the number of messages that were sent in the last 10 seconds?

Comment: Consider using [ratelimiter](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimiter/) python library. Then you can limit the messages your bot sending from your own code.

Comment: The problem isn't that my *bot* is sending too many messages, in the *server members*.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve messages sent within a certain period of time, you can use the [`TextChannel` history method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history):

In this method, there are two parameters that will interest you, before and after. You can specify a minimum date (in datetime or snowflake) and a maximum post date for the messages that will be returned in your channel history. So here it's after that will interest you, with your `datetime.now()` -10s.

(And then you apply `len()` on your history which is returned to you at the end)

---

**Attention**: discord.py is discontinued, use another fork, like [nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord).

Comment: This doesn't work:

```File "script.py", line 35
    async for message in channel.history(*, after=-10):


            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about `discord.py` being discontinued.